# Using Autofac with Prism's modules

Tags: c#, prism, autofac

I have a module called `ModuleA`. I created a resource dictionary file to point my application to appropriate location, and in my `Bootstraper.cs` file I put this code:

```
protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog() {
            return Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModuleCatalog.CreateFromXaml(
                new Uri("/MyProject;component/ModCatalog.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
```

When I run the app I'm getting this exception:

The requested service 'ModuleA' has not been registered.

The message is pretty clear for me, but how should I solve this? I intentionally created a resource dictionary - I didn't want to explicitly add a dependency on the main project. Do I have to register this type with Autofac in my main project (therefore adding it in references)?

Both Prism version, and Autofac are up to date.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override to methods in you bootstrapper like this,

```
    protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
    {
        return new PrioritisedDirectoryModuleCatalog();
    }

    protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog()
    {
        ((DirectoryModuleCatalog)ModuleCatalog).ModulePath = @".\Modules";
    }
```

this will tell your main project where to look for the modules

Then you need to rightclick on each of your modules and other project (not the main one), and specify Build Events (Just the Post-build event command line) that will tell each module where to put its dll, so the main project can find it.

the build event will look like something like this

xcopy /y "$(TargetPath)" "$(SolutionDir)NameOfYourProject\$(OutDir)Modules\"

if you create in file explorer in bin->debug new folder named Module, it should all work. Just make sure all the project point to that location from the post build event.

Now anytime you build it will output the dlls to that common location

I hope this helps :)

EDIT

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using Infrastructure.Prism.Attributes;
using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity;

 namespace Infrastructure.Prism.ModuleCatalog
 {
[SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.InheritanceDemand),   SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand)]
public class PrioritisedDirectoryModuleCatalog : DirectoryModuleCatalog
{
    /// <summary>
    /// load assemblies into different AppDomain, which is then discarded
    /// </summary>
    class ModulePriorityLoader : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Get the priority attribute of each module
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="modules"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1822:MarkMembersAsStatic"),
        SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Reliability", "CA2001:AvoidCallingProblematicMethods"
        , MessageId = "System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom")]
        public Dictionary<string, int> GetPriorities(IEnumerable<ModuleInfo> modules)
        {
            var priorities = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            var assemblies = new Dictionary<string, Assembly>();

            foreach (ModuleInfo module in modules)
            {
                if (!assemblies.ContainsKey(module.Ref))
                {
                    assemblies.Add(module.Ref, Assembly.LoadFrom(module.Ref));
                    //assemblies.Add(module.Ref, Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(module.Ref));
                }

                Type type = assemblies[module.Ref].GetExportedTypes()
                            .Where(p => p.AssemblyQualifiedName
                            .Equals(module.ModuleType, StringComparison.Ordinal)).First();

                var priorityAttribute = CustomAttributeData.GetCustomAttributes(type)
                                       .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Constructor
                                       .DeclaringType.FullName == typeof(PriorityAttribute).FullName);

                int priority = (priorityAttribute != null) ? (int)priorityAttribute.ConstructorArguments[0].Value : 0;

                priorities.Add(module.ModuleName, priority);
            }

            return priorities;
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get priority of each module, assign 0 if no priority assigned
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="modules"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private Dictionary<string, int> GetModulePriorities(IEnumerable<ModuleInfo> modules)
    {
        AppDomain childDomain = BuildChildDomain(AppDomain.CurrentDomain);
        try
        {
            Type loaderType = typeof(ModulePriorityLoader);
            var loader = (ModulePriorityLoader)childDomain
                        .CreateInstanceFrom(loaderType.Assembly.Location, 
                        loaderType.FullName).Unwrap();
            return loader.GetPriorities(modules);
        }
        finally
        {
            AppDomain.Unload(childDomain);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sort modules according to dependencies and priority
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="modules"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected override IEnumerable<ModuleInfo> Sort(IEnumerable<ModuleInfo> modules)
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> priorities = GetModulePriorities(modules);
        var result = new List<ModuleInfo>(base.Sort(modules));
        result.Sort((x, y) =>
        {
            return GetModulePriority(x, y, priorities);
        });
        return result;
    }

    private int GetModulePriority(ModuleInfo x, ModuleInfo y, 
    Dictionary<string, int> priorities)
    {
        var f2 = 0;
        string xModuleName = x.ModuleName;
        string yModuleName = y.ModuleName;
        if (x.DependsOn.Contains(yModuleName))
        {
            f2 = 1;
        }
        else if (y.DependsOn.Contains(xModuleName))
        {
            f2 = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            f2 = priorities[xModuleName].CompareTo(priorities[yModuleName]);
        }
        return f2;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Ok, but what about my DI container? It complains that it cannot find ModuleA which is correct because I didnt register it in bootstrapper and didn't add a reference in the main project.

Comment: where is that in the bootstrapper, where you register your modules? you don't have to register them if you use that line of code I have in CreateModuleCatalog instead of registering it.

Comment: Ok, I'll check it later At home

Comment: What's the namespace of the `PrioritisedDirectoryModuleCatalog` class? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: @SzwornyDziąch Hi, Im sorry its been a while since Ive done it, here is the code for the class (see edit), I took it from Plurasight course about prism. In my solution I have separate project called Infrastructure.Prism where I put all the staff related to prism, but you can put that class anywhere you want.